# Moxy JAXB and distringuishing between 'missing' versus explicit nulls

Tags: xml, jaxb, moxy

I really need to be able to distinguish between 'missing' and 'null' when unmarshalling XML into a POJO. I have an `Optional<BigInteger>` field and an adapter for `Optional` types:

```
public abstract class OptionalAdapter<T> extends XmlAdapter<T, Optional<T>> {

    @Override
    public Optional<T> unmarshal(T value) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Unmarshalling value: {}", value);

        if(value == null) {
            log.debug("Value is null, returning Optional.empty()");
            return Optional.empty();
        } else {
            log.debug("Value is not null, returning an optional holding the value");
            return Optional.of(value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T marshal(Optional<T> value) throws Exception {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return value.isPresent() ? value.get() : null;
    }
}
```

What I want is for XML which is missing a node for this `Optional<BigInteger>` field to NOT call the setter, but for any XML which DOES have a node which is empty (I have chosen this to represent explicit null) to call the setter which will set the field to `Optional.empty()`.

If I do this, the case for explicit null doesn't work:

```
@XmlNullPolicy(emptyNodeRepresentsNull = true, nullRepresentationForXml = XmlMarshalNullRepresentation.EMPTY_NODE, 
        isSetPerformedForAbsentNode =false)
private Optional<BigInteger> field;
```

The field is not set and remains `null`. If I set `isSetPerformedForAbsentNode` to `true`, then the case for missing node does not work. The setter is called with `null` and the field is set to `Optional.empty()`. Is there any way, I can configure some implementation of JAXB to what what I want? Absent and `null` mean very different things and I need to be able to tell the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use an element reference and the Moxy implementation of JaxB.

I placed the a `jaxb.properties` file in the package for my POJO with this property defined:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Then I declared two fields, the `Optional<BigInteger>` field that is the actual value of the property on the POJO and an element reference field that I use to determine whether the value is explicitly null or missing from the XML source.

```
private Optional<BigInteger> parentGroupId;
private JAXBElement<BigInteger> parentGroupIdElementRef;
```

My `Optional` adapter class:

```
public abstract class OptionalAdapter<T> extends XmlAdapter<T, Optional<T>> {

    @Override
    public Optional<T> unmarshal(T value) throws Exception {
        return Optional.of(value);
    }

    @Override
    public T marshal(Optional<T> value) throws Exception {
        return value.isPresent() ? value.get() : null;
    }
}
```

My handler for the element reference:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ParentGroupIdXmlElementRef {

    @XmlElementDecl(name="parentGroupId")
    public JAXBElement<BigInteger> createFooJAXBElement(final BigInteger value) {
        return new JAXBElement<>(new QName("parentGroupId"), BigInteger.class, value);
    }
}
```

My getters and setters in the POJO:

```
@XmlElement(required = false, nillable = true)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OptionalBigIntegerAdapter.class)
@XmlNullPolicy(isSetPerformedForAbsentNode = false, nullRepresentationForXml = XmlMarshalNullRepresentation.XSI_NIL)
@Override
public void setParentGroupId(final Optional<BigInteger> parent) {
    log.debug("Parent setter called: {}", parent);
    if (parent != null && parent.isPresent() && parent.get().signum() == -1) {
        throw log.throwing(new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot specify a parent group ID less than 0"));
    }
    this.parentGroupId = parent;
    //this.isParentIdMissing = false;

    if (parent == null) {
        parentGroupIdElementRef = null;
    } else if (parent.isPresent() && parentGroupIdElementRef == null) {
        parentGroupIdElementRef = new ParentGroupIdXmlElementRef().createFooJAXBElement(parent.get());
    } else if(parentGroupIdElementRef == null) {
        parentGroupIdElementRef = new ParentGroupIdXmlElementRef().createFooJAXBElement(null);
        parentGroupIdElementRef.setNil(true);
    }
}

@XmlElement(required = false, nillable = true)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OptionalBigIntegerAdapter.class)
@XmlNullPolicy(isSetPerformedForAbsentNode = false, nullRepresentationForXml = XmlMarshalNullRepresentation.XSI_NIL)
@Override
public @Nullable @Nonnegative Optional<BigInteger> getParentGroupId() {
    return parentGroupId;
}

@XmlElementRef(name="parentGroupId", required=false)
public void setParentGroupIdElementRef(final JAXBElement<BigInteger> elementRef) {
    log.debug("Setting element reference for parent ID: {}", elementRef);
    this.parentGroupIdElementRef = elementRef;

    if(parentGroupIdElementRef == null) {
        setParentGroupId(null);
    } else if(parentGroupIdElementRef.isNil()) {
        setParentGroupId(Optional.empty());
    } else {
        setParentGroupId(Optional.of(elementRef.getValue()));
    }
}

@XmlElementRef(name="parentGroupId", required=false)
public JAXBElement<BigInteger> getParentGroupIdElementRef() {
    log.debug("Getting Element reference: {}", parentGroupIdElementRef);
    return this.parentGroupIdElementRef;
}
```

Now all my unit tests pass. Non-null, null and missing are all appropriately handled.